# Facebook SDK unable to find class 'FacebookStream' in FacebookStreamHttpClient

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am trying to allow a user to log onto my site through the facebook SDK, and so far I have fixed all the errors until this one.
I get an error saying:

`Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStream' not found in C:\wamp\www\appname\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient.php on line 55`

I have re-installed the SDK and the same error is coming up.
my code is:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookStreamHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient; 
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '******','************' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://localhost/icemes/' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }
}  

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

  // print profile data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I bet you forgot to include a file. So use an autoloader instead that will do all the work for you. The Facebook SDK even includes one.

Comment: Upon using the autoload I get the error 'Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found'

Comment: How are you using the autoload?

Comment: `require_once('Facebook/autoload.php')` Tried using a use statement after this too but the error is the same.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: According to Wamp, 5.4.16

Comment: And how do you use FacebookSession?

Comment: I am now using it as `use Facebook\FacebookSession;` and have the error `Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found`